# On the property of Gauss sum

Tags: gauss-sums, dirichlet-character

In the book of a classical introduction to modern number theory by Kenneth Ireland and Michael Rosen page 92
in the proof of proposition 8.2.2 of gauss sum, I don't understand how he gets this

$ \sum_{x} \sum_{y} \chi(x) \bar{\chi(y)} \delta(x,y)p =p(p-1)$

Where $\delta(x, y)$ is one if $x\equiv y \pmod p$ and zero otherwise , x, y $\in$ $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ , and $\chi $ is dirichlet character mod $p $.

Comment: When you sum over $y$, only the term $y=x$ is counted because there is a $\delta(y,x)$. So the sum over $y$ is always $|\chi^2(x)|p=p$. And the sum of $|\chi|^2$ is $p-1$.

Comment: But we have two sums , on x and y  do they become one sum when we add the condition $x=y$?if yes why?

Comment: Can you write all the steps because I didn't understand your argument

Comment: Why don’t you write this out? Take $p=5$ or something, take $\chi(x)$ equal to (say) $1$ if $x=1,4$, $-1$ if $x=2,3$ and $0$ if $x=0$. Write the entire double sum (take $x=0$ and write the sum over $y$, then write $x=1$ and the sum over $y$ and so on...), it’s really not difficult to spot the simplification.

Comment: @Mindlack But you did't answer my question do the two sum became one under the condition x=y or not

Comment: In the sum over $y$, no term except the one with $y=x$ counts so the total is the term with $y=x$. So yes, in some sense, the two sums “become one” and you replace $y$ with $x$. But you’ll understand it far better if you write it out once to *see* what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide both sides of the equation
$$ \sum_x \sum_y \chi(x) \overline{\chi(y)} \delta(x,y)p = p(p-1) \tag{1} $$
by $\,p\,$ to get
$$ \sum_x \sum_y \chi(x) \overline{\chi(y)} \delta(x,y)  = (p-1). \tag{2} $$
The double sum in this new equation is essentially the trace of a matrix.

More precisely, if $\,A:=\{A_{i,j}\}\,$ is any matrix, then by definition,
its trace
$$ \text{tr}(A) := \sum_i A_{i,i} = \sum_i \sum_j A_{i,j}\delta_{ij} \tag{3} $$
can be written either as a single sum or else, using the
[Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta),
as an equivalent double sum. The
same holds for equation $(2)$.

---

An alternative method is the following
$$ \sum_y \chi(x) \overline{\chi(y)} \delta(x,y)\,p
 = \chi(x) \overline{\chi(x)} \,p
 = \sum_y |\chi(x)|^2\ \tag{4} $$
where the first sum is equivalent to a single value since only
terms with $\,y=x\,$ are non-zero.

Equation $(1)$ can now be rewritten as
$$ S:=\sum_x \sum_y \chi(x) \overline{\chi(y)} \delta(x,y)p =
  \sum_x \sum_y |\chi(x)|^2\ = \sum_y\left(\sum_x |\chi(x)|^2\right). \tag{5}$$
Now, by definition of $\,\chi\,$ we have $\,|\chi(x)|^2=1\,$ iff $\,x\ne 0,\,$
or written another way, $\,|\chi(x)|^2 = 1 - \delta(x,0).\,$ Thus we have
$$ S = \sum_y \left(\sum_x 1-\delta(x,0)\right) = p(p-1) \tag{6} $$
where the right side is $\,p(p-1)\,$ because $\,1-\delta(x,0)\,$ is $1$
iff $\,x\ne 1\,$ and there are exactly $\,p(p-1)\,$ such pairs $\,(y,x).$